# 2012 Election: Four(?) New Moderators

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, election, moderators

The [2012 Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election) ended a few hours ago and the three available position were fill via the democratic process. Congratulations to the three new moderators: [Brad Larson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19679), [George Stocker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16587), and [ThiefMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298479)! ...except there are **four** new moderators.  This fourth moderator seems to have been "called up after the election to meet additional demand".  But the election only finished a couple hours ago, what influx of demand has occurred in the last few hours?

Though [jjnguy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2598) appears qualified, this appointment appears underhand. If there was a clear need for four moderators, why did the community not have the chance to elect four moderators?

Comment: You're reading it wrong and the layout of the page is on marijuana

Comment: Aha... I see, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

jjnguy was called up after the *last* election.

He was the runner up, they needed more people, mostly democratic.

Answer (score 16):

The link under his name goes to the **November 2011** election. He was called up afterwards to fill the spot Anna Lear had taken. She was hired as Community Manager after the election which left the 4th space open from that election.